# How to return only ONE matching subdocument (not array) from subdocument array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subdocument

In my collection:

```
{ "code": xx1
  "valueList": [
                  { "id": "yy1", "name": "name1"},
                  { "id": "yy2", "name": "name2"},
                  { "id": "yy3", "name": "name3"}              
               ]
},
{ "code": xx2
  "valueList": [
                  { "id": "yy4", "name": "name4"},
                  { "id": "yy5", "name": "name5"},
                  { "id": "yy6", "name": "name6"}              
               ]
}
```

I want to return specific ONE matching subdocument (not an array), like below:

```
{ "id": "yy3", "name": "name3"}
```

I try below code:

```
findOne({ "code": "xx1",
          "valueList.name": "yy3"
       })
.select({ "valueList.$": 1});
```

It returns an array instead:

```
 {
   "valueList": [{ "id": "yy3", "name": "name3" }]
 }
```

How can I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $match: { "valueList.id": "yy3" } },
    { $unwind: "$valueList" },
    { $match: { "valueList.id": "yy3" } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$valueList" } }
])
```

First [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) will filter out all unnecessary documents, then you can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get `valueList` item per document and then `$match` again to get only the one with `yy3` in the last stage you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote `valueList` item to the top level.

Comment: It works but is returning an array: [{ "id": "yy3", "name": "name3"} ]. Is it possible it can just return the subdocument itself without the array: { "id": "yy3", "name": "name3"} (note: without the [ ])? It will be perfect then, thank you

Comment: @elvin, that needs to be handled in your app logic, aggregate and find will always return an array, even if it's one-element array